# how to interact with embedded google calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, calendar, same-origin-policy

I've embedded Google Calendar into HTML page. It has a big number of calendars in it, so, to make it nice I'd like all the calendars to be turned off by default.

It seems that jQuery [can't help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe), due to same origin policy.

Is there a simple straight-forward "just-make-it-work" solution?

**EDIT:** in the question [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) there was a word about using local proxy for this task. What is it and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best solution is to pull in the calendar feeds and present the calendar yourself.

Same-origin policy will always bite you.  jQuery is just JavaScript.  It isn't magic, and if it cannot access something, neither will any other client-side scripts you write.

Proxying something as complex as the Google Calendar isn't a good idea.  Even if you get it working, they may change it in the future.

It's trivial to pull in their XML.  You can find the URL right on the same panel that you got the HTML for the shared calendar.  Then, you can load all of those server-side and present them on your page however you would like.